# Send Keystroke to a generic window c++ with SendInput

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a C++ console application that would to send some Keystroke to one generic window...
I'm trying to find ALL OPEN WINDOW WITH MESSAGE QUEUE (for input) with `EnumWindows()` and my callback store some information about, it has `GetWindowText()`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and `PostThreadMessage()` (to check if has Message queue, with `WM_NULL` message) and also its `HWND hWnd` ... **[code below]**

**Hints:** Is this correct or I should use **also** `EnumChildWindows()` ?

**continue...**

I wish to send keystroke for example `ALT+F4` or `CTRL+T` etc. to one of the windows ...

**Hints:** Which is the best way to do this? `SendInput()` or `PostThreadMessage()` ?

**[HALF auto-reply]:**  I'm currently trying `SendInput()`, sending a group of `INPUT` using the translation of Scan Code in VirtualKey with `myVKey = MapVirtualKeyEx(..., MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK, ...)` , for example `ALT` and `F4` is `56` and `62` as `int` type, in `HEX` is `38` and `3E` ... I make input with `dwFlags = 0` and after, in reverse order, with `dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`
(I need to handle only a group of command, no other like single char etc..);

**I think VKey is better than Hardware Scan Code (right?)**

**Third Question: Before using `SendInput()`, how I should bring the window?**
Let's supposing I have all info about the window...

What and in which order I must use `SetFocus()`, `SetActiveWindow()` and / or `SetForegroundWindow()` ? **[all are commented]**

**a bit of code:**

```
bool _res = false;
_res = AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), targetThreadID, TRUE);
if (!_res) {
    cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
else {
    //SetFocus(focusHandler);
    //SetActiveWindow(focusHandler);
    //SetForegroundWindow(focusHandler);
enter code here
    if (!prevH) {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else {
    UINT res = SendInput(nTotVKey, numInputVect, sizeof(INPUT));
    if (res != nTotVKey) {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else {
        _res = AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), targetThreadID, FALSE);
        if (!_res) {
            cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

**EDIT: REAL SCENARIO** Is a C/S application in which client says "I do a CTRL+W to the selected window" and Imagine a C# client that send to the server a "CTRL+W" message for Google Chrome (for example) that the server should send to its thread input queue... I need to put in foregound "Google Chrome" to send the input "CTRL+W" ..don't worry about any race condition or other.. If needed the client will send again the command...

Comment: One question per question please!

Comment: You're right but the first two are related with the final question.

Comment: You don't need to `PostMessage` to find out, whether a window is owned by a thread with a message queue. Any thread that owns a window has a message queue. In fact, any thread that has called a USER32 API has a message queue. If you want to send input to a specific window, the only reliable and supported approach is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Everything else (including your hack with `AttachThreadInput`) will fail, one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. I've found my answers on StackOverflow's past questions.

1: **Is this correct or I should use also `EnumChildWindows()` ?**

A: **NO** I don't need it because almost of Child will receive the input from parent.

2: **Which is the best way to do this? `SendInput()` or `PostThreadMessage()` ?**

A: `SendInput()` with Virtual Key.

3: **What and in which order I must use SetFocus(), SetActiveWindow() and / or** `SetForegroundWindow()`**?**

A: Is enough `SetFocus()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you'd need `EnumChildWindows()`. You'll have to provide more clear information as to why `EnumWindows()` isn't working.

Second, `PostMessage()` is probably the most gentle approach for sending messages to another window. However, depending on how each application handles its own input, your messages may be ignored or filtered. If you know which application you'll be targeting and how it responds to messages, I'd used `PostThreadMessage()` if you can.

Only the window with keyboard focus will see key messages sent via `SendInput()`. Further, if you want to send key messages that include modified sequences, keys like ctrl, alt, shift; you'll have have to send sequences like: `make ctrl, make T, break T, break ctrl`.

My advice: don't worry about **Scan Codes**, you should only have to deal with **Virtual Keys**. Scan Codes are legacy; USB keyboard hardware doesn't even produce them (Windows does).

Third, all you should need is `SetForgroundWindow()`.

Comment: `PostThreadMessage()` cannot target a specific HWND, you have to use `PostMessage()` instead, however [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). As for the race condition on `SendInput()`, do not send multiple keystrokes with multiple calls to `SendInput()`. Call it *once* with multiple `INPUT`s instead. It avoids interleaving the provided array with user typing. This is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Comment: And there are many restrictions on `SetForegroundWindow()` which are [also documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx), not to mention the race condition that the user can change the foreground window at any time..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the post with the real scenario of the application. It doesn't matter about any race condition or similar... Is a C/S application in which client says "I do a CTRL+W to the selected window" and Imagine a C# client that send to the server a "CTRL+W" message for Google Chrome (for example) that the server should send to its thread input queue... I need to put in foregound "Google Chrome" to send the input "CTRL+W"

Comment: The edit didn't make your answer much better. You still insist, that `PostThreadMessage` could be used to send a message to a window. That's not the case. And your paragraph on `SendInput` goes on and on about what can go wrong, if you use it in a way it wasn't meant to be used. Why not simply suggest to use it the way it's meant to be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows 8 or your Windows 10  is blocking you.

In the Windows 8 security model, apps don’t have the privileges required to be a UI automation client. But you can write a desktop app that acts as an automation client with your app as the target. To do this, your desktop automation client app needs to be built with UIAccess permissions.

Change the manifest to  UIAccess="true" and aquire administrator priviledge, create a certificate, sign the application with that certificate, put it in a location under Program Files, and run it. As explained here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and here

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4b6dbc43-a026-4957-9178-91d2001e2d0d/windows-8-block-alttab-simulation#291eb5b4-f6d2-49b6-83db-658bd832f2c9

plus this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and this

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fitasupport%2Farchive%2F2009%2F09%2F16%2Fsendsas-step-by-step.aspx&edit-text=&act=url

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I read it at all (hope) but SendSAS() is unknown (Windows.h already included with sas.h)